# How to write a hive script for the expected output

Tags: hadoop, hive

```
event1  id1 foo_id1
event1  id1 foo_id2
event1  id1 foo_id3
event1  id1 foo_id4
event1  id1 foo_id1
event1  id2 foo_id1
event1  id2 foo_id2
event1  id3 foo_id1
event1  id1 foo_id1
event1  id3 foo_id3
event1  id4 foo_id1
event1  id4 foo_id2
event1  id1 foo_id1
event1  id4 foo_id3
event1  id4 foo_id4
event2      foo_id1
event2      foo_id2
event2      foo_id3
event2      foo_id3
```

All events(ie,event1, event2) have foo_ids. For all events in "event1", I would like to know how many times those foo_id(s) occur in event2.

I want the o/p like this:

```
id1    foo_id1  1
id1    foo_id2  1
id1    foo_id3  1
id2    foo_id1  1
id2    foo_id2  1
```

How to write a hive script to return the data in the expected format

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table1
SELECT  e1.id, e1.foo_id, count(e2.foo_id)
FROM events e1
LEFT OUTER JOIN events e2
ON e1.foo_id = e2.foo_id 
WHERE e2.event = 'event2' 
AND e1.event = 'event1' 
GROUP BY e1.id, e1.foo_id;
```

I tried the above hive script. but, the o/p shows like this:

```
    id1 foo_id1 4
    id1 foo_id2 1
    id1 foo_id3 2
    id2 foo_id1 1
    id2 foo_id2 1
```

How to write a hive script to return the data in the expected format?

Comment: I need the output as
id1    foo_id1  1
id1    foo_id2  1
id1    foo_id3  1
id2    foo_id1  1
id2    foo_id2  1

How do I write a hive script to get an output as above.

Answer (score 1):

If it's just a matter of formatting and setting the third column as **count=x**, then you can use the `concat` UDF in Hive:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE table1
SELECT  e1.id, e1.foo_id, concat('count=', count(e2.foo_id))
FROM events e1
LEFT OUTER JOIN events e2
ON e1.foo_id = e2.foo_id 
WHERE e2.event = 'event2' 
AND e1.event = 'event1' 
GROUP BY e1.id, e1.foo_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Count=x is not the expected output. I need to get the output with the foo_id in the order of relevance.
Above I have mentioned the format of the expected ouput.